# Show those data which satisfied the condition in list view?

Tags: android, json, listview

This is my custom list view adapter.My problem is very simple but I am stuck on this.I am displaying some data in list view  in three different text views.Text description(txtDesc), text title and text title2.I wanted to show only those titles which have text description as "video".Data are coming from URL as JSON objects using volley library.
I tried if condition and comparing the string but the app crashes.Any help will be great.
//Details class is my getter and setter class

```
 public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {

Context context;
String vid = "Video";

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             List<Details> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    //ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtTitle2;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Details rowItem = (Details) getItem(position);
    //Details rowItem = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    String vid = "Video";
    if (convertView == null )
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

             holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
             holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.link);            
              convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else


        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getResType());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getName());
    holder.txtTitle2.setText(rowItem.getUrl());


    // holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: App crashes means you may have got stack trace.. Post that too.

Comment: String vid = "Video";
        if (convertView == null && holder.txtDesc.equals(vid) )
         I tried some thin like this shows nullable reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you told in the comment you were checking vid with this,

```
holder.txtDesc.equals(vid)
```

But `holder.textDesc` is a `TextView` So I think you have to check like this

```
rowItem.getResType().toString().equals(vid)
```

**Update**

Reformat your codes like this

```
if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); //TODO: parent instead of null?
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    //Your initializations
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Comment: getting this  run time error    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.view.View.getTag()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.wonder5.spinnerexample.CustomListViewAdapter.getView(CustomListViewAdapter.java:56)

Comment: thanks @Krishna do I use nested if-else to check my condition

Comment: It's not required but I recommend that, And check the string `vid` as I told above

Answer (score 1):

Check this getView method of yours.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Details rowItem = (Details) getItem(position);
        //Details rowItem = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        String vid = "Video";
        if (convertView == null )
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

                 holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                 holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.link);            
                  convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else


            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getResType());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getName());
        holder.txtTitle2.setText(rowItem.getUrl());
        String url=rowItem.getUrl();
        if(url.contains("video")){
        holder.txtDesc.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        holder.txtTitle.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        holder.txtTitle2.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        }else{
        holder.txtDesc.setvisibility(View.GONE)
        holder.txtTitle.setvisibility(View.GONE)
        holder.txtTitle2.setvisibility(View.GONE)
        }


        // holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When you pass a set of array to Adapter, then Adapter size will be equals to your items. while in getView()/other way you can not skip one item(s) as it does not meet your condition(s).
2. Solution : What you can do is before passing items to adapter, filter the list with your condition(s) and set it to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    if(rowItem.getResType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")){
    holder.txtDesc.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtTitle.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtTitle2.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getResType());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getName());
    holder.txtTitle2.setText(rowItem.getUrl());
    }else{
    holder.txtDesc.setvisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.txtTitle.setvisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.txtTitle2.setvisibility(View.GONE);}
```